# Laravel - Auth multi guard loginUsingId is not working as expexted

Tags: laravel, authentication

I gotta problem with laravel Auth multi guard technology,
here is my config file

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'admin',
    ],

'guards' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'user',
        ],

        'front' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'front',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Modules\Admin\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'front' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Modules\WebUser\Models\WebUser::class,
        ],
    ],
```

The problem is that when I try to login by using front guard with id (primary key) like this `Auth::guard('front')->loginUsingId(1);` it returns me null, when I do like this `Auth::loginUsingId(1);` it logs me in, the this is that is working only with default guard, when I change defaults it works, but when trying to use a guard to login which is not set as default, then it does nothing. Any ideas why? May be I am missing something or what

Comment: Test the eloquent provider first:  `app(Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::class, ['model' => App\Modules\WebUser\Models\WebUser::class])->retrieveById(1);`

Comment: I tested it before, it is retrieving the user data

Answer (score 2):

According to how laravel works, this

```
Auth::guard('front')->loginUsingId(1);
```

will always return null. But trust me the Auth helper is working perfectly here.
To check if the user logged in or not

```
return Auth::guard('front')->user();
```

That will make a lot of sense once you see the output above.

Answer (score 1):

Then you execute this:

```
Auth::guard('front')->loginUsingId(1);
```

You has been successfully logged in. You can test it with:

```
Auth::guard('front')->id();
```

If you try testing

```
auth()->id();
```

you will get 'null', because it's checking only default guard

Answer (score -1):

You can try this solution:

```
Auth::guard('web')->loginUsingId(1);

$user=Auth::user();

$user->created_at=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$user->save();
```